# How to avoid creating a build directory when running a gradle task?

Tags: gradle, gwt, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to run a very simple task to show the included `build.gradle` repositories.

```gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.0.8"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
}
...
apply plugin: 'gwt-compiler'
...
task showRepos {
    group 'Circus'
    description 'Show all included repositories'
    doLast {
        println "\nAll repos:"
        println repositories.collect { it.name } 
        println "\n"
    }
}
```

However, when I run this with `gradle showRepos` it automatically creates the  *"build"* directory:

```
build/
└── gwt
    ├── cache
    ├── extra
    ├── gen
    └── work
```

**How can I prevent this automatic creation?**

---

**UPDATE-1**

Seem to be some naughty GWT configure stuff running...

```
# gradle showRepos --console verbose --info

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'circuitjs' using build file 'F:\...\build.gradle'.
Using gwt.args for test: 
    -war     F:\...\war 
    -extra   F:\...\build\gwt\extra 
    -workDir F:\...\build\gwt\work 
    -gen     F:\...\build\gwt\gen 
    -logLevel INFO
Using gwt.persistentunitcachedir for test: {0}
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'showRepos' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':showRepos']
:showRepos (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) started.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What task are you running from command line? If you are running

```
gradle showRepos
```

Then it shouldn't create those GWT folders. I'm guessing either

1. You have a gwt task in your task graph (ie you are running a task which has a dependency on a gwt task)
2. You have a naughty gwt task which is creating folders in the configuration phase (when it should only occur in the execution phase)

Comment: See [build phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases). You shouldn't do any actual "work" in the configuration phase. I'm guessing you will move some mkdir etc in your gwt task inside a `doFirst {...} ` closure so that it occurs in the execution phase

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. What do I have to do?

Comment: Well... Without seeing the logic that creates the directories it's very difficult to help

Comment: That's why I'm asking here. If I knew the logic, I could prevent it from happening. Probably hidden away in the sources of `gwt-gradle-plugin` or `gradle` itself.

Comment: Nothing to do with gradle, it'll be the GWT gradle plugin

Comment: Indeed there is buggy behavior in that plugin